# A DMM low current measurement question

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter

I'm stuck with a question when reading a textbook:

The question is a situation as follows:

---

The very high internal resistance of digital multi-meters, in their voltage measuring ranges, can be used to measure extremely low currents (even though the DMM may not offer a low current range explicitly).

Suppose, for example, you want to measure the small current that flows through a 1000 Mohm "leakage" resistance (that term is used to describe a small current that ideally should be absent entirely, for example through the insulation of an underground cable).

You have available a standard DMM, whose 2V DC range has 10 Mohm internal resistance, and you have available a dc source of +10 V.

How can you use what you've got to measure accurately the leakage resistance?

---

Anyone can understand this question and have an idea?

edit:

[image]

Comment: Draw the schematic of everything connected, and then solve for each component.

Comment: The point is there is no schematics in the question.

Comment: That is why I told you to draw the schematic

Comment: Hint: If you have a small current, say 1nA flowing across 10Mohms, what voltage do you see?

Comment: Your DMM forms part of a voltage divider with the 'leakage' resistor. You know its resistance and its telling you the voltage its measuring - so you can solve for the current flowing.

Comment: Does current times resistance mean anything to you? Have you specified a current? Have you specified a resistance? Hmmm?

Comment: What is that 10V DC source can be used there?

Comment: Are you all saying the same current will pass through the 1000 Mohm and 10 Mohm series in ammeter mode and from voltage reading I can derive the current V_measured/10 Mohm? But what is that 10V DC to use for?

Comment: 10V DC is a supply voltage for your voltage divider. Rleak = 100Mohms and Rdmm = 10Mohms we have V = 10V*10M/(100M + 10M) = 0.909V and this voltage will appear on your DMM display in "voltage mode".

Comment: I think I cannot picture what this question is talking about. Isnt the leakage resistor connected to a circuitry and a very leakage current flows thorugh? I would appreciate if someone can draw what he understands from this. English is not my mother tounge maybe thats why..

Comment: Try it yourself by using two DMM connected in series to some DC voltage.

Comment: Hint #2: Your 10 volt source is in series with the 1G ohm leakage path which is in series with your meter with an input resistance of 10M ohm. It is simple division - twice. Or you can use ratios.

Comment: Please see my edit illustration: Is this the scenario to measure leakage resistor (Rx)?

Comment: Yes that's it  .

Comment: @brhans thanks for reply actually it is easy as a question but was hard what the question meant for me.

Comment: The source negative terminal must be connected to ground/DMM common.

Comment: But there isn't a V reading on the DMM. You have it plugged in on series as a current reader.... The DMM doesn't show its internal voltage drop does it? Of course if it shows the current then it's deduced. ix10MOhm.

Comment: Forget for a moment that it's a DMM. Think of it as simply a 10M resistor. You apply 10 volts to the circuit, and you measure the voltage across that resistor. How much current is flowing, and what is the resistance of the other resistor?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved; I used voltage divider:
10/(1000M+10M) = Vddm/10M
so Vdd = (10 x 10 M) / 1010M = 0.099V

I = (10V - 0.099V)/1000M = 9.901x10^-9A